# Can't install module v.0.6rc1 on my Mac by easy_install

Tags: python, easy-install, spyder

I am green to Python. These day I need to install GA package in my python. I follow the documentation to use easy_install to install it.(http://pyevolve.sourceforge.net/0_6rc1/intro.html#download-sec)

Unfortunately, when I run the easy_install, it comes out a syntax problem.

easy_install pyevolve
  File "", line 1
    easy_install pyevolve
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I have searched online a lot but not find such similar case. I think I did install the setuptools beforehand. Could anyone help me out of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running a shell command from within the Python interpreter. Quit Python, open Terminal.app, and rerun your command.